# how to make V. for versicle indented and in red

Tags: renewcommand, stackengine

I am typesetting an Orthodox liturgical text and would like to typeset a versicle (V.) before certain verses. I am currently using the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{Orthodox Liturgical Text}
\author{Doc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\versicle}{\kern-0.25em \stackinset{r}{0.33ex}{c}{}{\rotatebox{-30}{\normalsize$\rceil$}}{V}}

\newcommand{\response}{\kern-0.25em\stackinset{r}{0.35ex}{c}{}{ \rotatebox{-30}{\normalsize$\rceil$}}{R}}

\newcommand\instruct[1]{%
{\noindent\normalsize\itshape\selectfont\color{red}
    {#1}\normalsize}%
}

\newcommand\vers[1]{%
\noindent\normalsize\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}\normalsize\normalfont%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\vers{(1.)} For His mercy is confirmed on us, and the truth of the Lord endures forever.\\

\instruct{Insert the appointed Doxastikon is there is one.}\\

\versicle Glory to the Father, and to the Son, and to the Holy Spirit.\\

\instruct{Insert the appointed Dogmatikon, Theotokion, or Doxastikon. Then:}\\

\versicle Now and ever and unto ages of ages. Amen.\\

\end{document}
```

What I would like is the V (for the versicle) to be indented and in red, like the (1). I have not too much, if any experience with the structure of the versicle and repsonse commands and where to add in coding to make the (V). indented and in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `\normalfont` and `\normalsize` commands are out of place. If you happen to set some part in `\footnotesize`, for instance, you'd get normal size symbols, larger than the context.

The `\kern` command doesn't do what you maybe expect, best to avoid it if you don't know about its features.

This said, you don't get an indent because you're suppressing it with `\noindent`. However I'd use a different strategy.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\versiclesymbol}{%
  \stackinset{r}{0.33ex}{c}{}{\rotatebox{-30}{$\rceil$}}{V}%
}

\newcommand{\responsesymbol}{%
  \stackinset{r}{0.35ex}{c}{}{\rotatebox{-30}{$\rceil$}}{R}%
}

\newcommand\instruct[1]{%
  \par\noindent\textcolor{red!80}{\itshape#1}%
}

\newcommand\vers[1]{%
  \par\textcolor{red!80}{\bfseries#1}\ \ignorespaces
}

\newcommand{\versicle}{\vers{\versiclesymbol}}
\newcommand{\response}{\vers{\responsesymbol}}

\begin{document}

\vers{(1.)} For His mercy is confirmed on us, and the truth of the Lord endures forever.

\instruct{Insert the appointed Doxastikon is there is one.}

\versicle Glory to the Father, and to the Son, and to the Holy Spirit.

\instruct{Insert the appointed Dogmatikon, Theotokion, or Doxastikon. Then:}

\versicle Now and ever and unto ages of ages. Amen.

\response Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! You're right, I really don't know anything about the '\ker' command.                                               So, basically I do not need '\normal font' and 'normal size' at all?

Comment: I am also getting the following:                                                          'Command \versicle already defined. ...command{\versicle}{\vers{\versiclesymbol}}'     when I compile.

Comment: @Doc Not with the code I suggested. Check it. Yes, you don't need `\normalfont` and `\normalsize`. They might even do harm.

Comment: Thanks so much, I am sorry I thought I checked your solution last November,  but didn't. I am sorry and thanks for the solution.